# Show with the intermediate value theorem that f(x)=314 has a solution.

Tags: calculus

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-|\; x\;| }}+\frac{1}{x^{4}}$$

I was asked to show though the intermediate value theorem that $f(x)$ has at least one solution when $f(x)=314$. I found that $f(x)$ is continuous when $-1<x<0$ and $0<x<1$. The problem I'm having is that I thought that the theorem only worked for closed intervalls.
Any tips are greatly appreciated!

Comment: please use MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When $x=0.000001, f$ is huge.  When $x=0.5$, $f$ is small.  Somewhere in the middle is $314$.